# ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism set to -1

Tags: vb.net, parallel.foreach

Please see the code below:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType(ScheduledTasks))

Private Shared TestString As String = ""

Public Shared Sub writeConsole(ByVal i As Integer)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    TestString = TestString & i
End Sub

Public Shared Sub ParallelTest()

    Dim int1 As Integer = 1, int2 As Integer = 2, int3 As Integer = 3, int4 As Integer = 4, int5 As Integer = 5, int6 As Integer = 6, int7 As Integer = 7, int8 As Integer = 8, int9 As Integer = 9, int10 As Integer = 10
    Dim list As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    list.Add(int1)
    list.Add(int2)
    list.Add(int3)
    list.Add(int4)
    list.Add(int5)
    list.Add(int6)
    list.Add(int7)
    list.Add(int8)
    list.Add(int9)
    list.Add(int10)

    Dim ParallelOptions As ParallelOptions = New ParallelOptions
    ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 ' Environment.ProcessorCount * 10
    Parallel.ForEach(Of Integer)(list.AsEnumerable(),
                               Sub(test As Integer)
                                   writeConsole(test)
                               End Sub)
    MsgBox("got here")
```

When the code reaches the message box, TestString contains the following value: 16237594810.  I would expect it to be: 12345678910.  It seems to indicate that multiple threads are being used even though MaxDegreeOfParallelism is set to: 1.  Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure it is set to 1? `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1`. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx): If it is -1, there is no limit on the number of concurrently running operations.

Comment: @Pro Grammer, it is definitely set to 1.

Comment: Okay, so I just did some testing with the code you provided, and it seems that when you call `Sleep` on the thread, it then picks up a new thread. Replace your writeConsole parameter with string, and replace the call to it with `writeConsole(test & " - " & Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId & vbCrLf)` so you can see the thread ID against each number

Comment: It doesn't seem to actually change when I modify the max value, but it shows the thread IDs change on sleep